# :authenticate_user! function not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise in a ruby-on-rails project, and `before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:show]` is not working when I use it in UsersController :

```
# ./controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:show]

  def show
  end
end

# ./config/routes.rb
Notify::Application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :users 
  ...
end
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Error message whould be nice. Is your helper methode really called `authenticate_user!`?

Comment: no error message, just showing the page as if user was authenticated (which cause errors related to that)

Comment: I think it might be because you are inheriting from `Devise::SessionsController`, are you certain you want to be doing that?

Comment: I've put the `show` action in an other controller which is inheriting from `ApplicationController` instead, and it works ! thanks for the tip

Comment: Iam going through the same problem, did you work it out?

Comment: yes, the conflict was because of `Devise::SessionsController` so I moved the action into another controller